# How would one programmatically stop an app from reading computer files?

Tags: python, security, scripting, permissions

In a language like Python for scripting, how would you stop an app from having access to reading computer files, especially sensitive system-level ones?

Edit: To be clear, I mean set permissions for that app to not have access to computer files, even after the script is done running (setting permissions).

Comment: By running it as a user that doesn't have access to said files. Generally, this is a file-system permission issue, not a programming one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run your python script as a non-privileged user
and read a file after validating the access

```
# check readability of the path 
if os.access("file.txt", os.R_OK):  
    # open txt file as file 
    with open("file.tx") as file: 
        return file.read()
```

Comment: Hey Vivek, thanks for your answer. I should have been more clear, but I meant to change permissions of the app itself to not read files anymore, even after the script is running (permission setting).